# HTML5 Video player using Laravel

Tags: laravel, html5-video, laravel-5.6

I want to create a video player using HTML in Laravel
I use below code its work fine for some video

```
$link = 'uploads/'.$video->link;
<video  width="720" height="540" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="{{URL::asset($link)}}" type="video/{{$video->extention }}">
</video>
```

but probelm is in my database **link** column data is like:- '***Natural animal hd video.mp4***'

In this case its fail

Comment: Does it show any errors? Where are your videos stored?

Comment: You can use `Str::slug($video_file_name)` to save filename in database as well as in storage

Comment: it shows Failed to load /Project/uploads/Natural%20animal%20hd%20video.mp4:1 resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: thanks guys ,Actually i missed public forlder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = 'public/uploads/'.$video->link;
```

add